# Proper Many-to-Many relations in GraphQL with AWS AppSync?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm creating a family tree API using AWS Amplify and AppSync thereof. The FamilyTree is based on Persons having parents, children and marriages. The marriage is what I'm struggling with. To start, here's the input to GraphQL Transform ("schema"):

```
type Person @model {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String!
  marriages: [Married] @connection(name: "marriedToA")
  marriedTo: [Married] @connection(name: "marriedToB")
  parents: [Related] @connection(name: "parentOf")
  children: [Related] @connection(name: "childOf")
}

type Related @model {
  id: ID!
  parent: Person @connection(name: "childOf")
  child: Person @connection(name: "parentOf")
}

type Married @model {
  id: ID!
  partnerA: Person @connection(name: "marriedToB")
  partnerB: Person @connection(name: "marriedToA")
  dateMarried: String!
}
```

While the many-to-many solution for children and parents works fine (despite being a bit nested), the marriage does not really solve the problem. So when I query like this:

```
query ListPersons {
  listPersons(limit: 10) {
    items {
      firstName
      children {
        items {
          child {
            firstName
          }
        }
      }
      parents {
        items {
          parent {
            firstName
          }
        }
      }
      marriages {
        items {
          partnerA {
            firstName
          }
          partnerB {
            firstName
          }
        }
      }
      marriedTo {
        items {
          partnerA {
            firstName
          }
          partnerB {
            firstName
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "listPersons": {
      "items": [
        {
          "firstName": "Bob",
          "children": {
            "items": []
          },
          "parents": {
            "items": [
              {
                "parent": {
                  "firstName": "John"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "marriages": {
            "items": []
          },
          "marriedTo": {
            "items": []
          }
        },
        {
          "firstName": "John",
          "children": {
            "items": [
              {
                "child": {
                  "firstName": "Bob"
                }
              },
              {
                "child": {
                  "firstName": "Kyle"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "parents": {
            "items": []
          },
          "marriages": {
            "items": []
          },
          "marriedTo": {
            "items": [
              {
                "partnerA": {
                  "firstName": "John"
                },
                "partnerB": {
                  "firstName": "Jane"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "firstName": "Kyle",
          "children": {
            "items": []
          },
          "parents": {
            "items": [
              {
                "parent": {
                  "firstName": "John"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "marriages": {
            "items": []
          },
          "marriedTo": {
            "items": []
          }
        },
        {
          "firstName": "Jane",
          "children": {
            "items": []
          },
          "parents": {
            "items": []
          },
          "marriages": {
            "items": [
              {
                "partnerA": {
                  "firstName": "John"
                },
                "partnerB": {
                  "firstName": "Jane"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "marriedTo": {
            "items": []
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So now the client logic would always have to check the fields marriages *and* marriedTo. What I really want is though, *one* field for a list of marriages of that person and through which I can query the partner(s). Is that achievable with Amplify and AppSync?